# combining a new list with two base lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numbers

I would like to combine two lists by organizing them in a way where the first element of the first is the first item of the new list and the first element of the second is the second element of the new list and so on

```
count = 12
list = list(range(count))

list1 = []
list2 = []

for x in range(0, count, 4):
    list1.append(x)

for y in range(3, count, 4):
    list2.append(y)

#Concatenate doesn't work
newlist = list1 + list2

print(newlist)
print(list)
```

The result of this is:

```
newlist = [0, 4, 8, 3, 7, 11]
```

But I want something like this:

```
newlist = [0, 3, 4, 7, 8, 11]
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can use `sorted` to archieve your result

```py
count = 12
list = list(range(count))

list1 = []
list2 = []

for x in range(0, count, 4):
    list1.append(x)

for y in range(3, count, 4):
    list2.append(y)

print(list1)# ==> [0, 4, 8]
print(list2)# ==> [3, 7, 11]
newlist = list1 + list2
print(sorted(newlist))# ==> [0, 3, 4, 7, 8, 11]
```

Comment: That assumes the values should be sorted. That happens to be what OP shows as an example, but it won't work in general.

Comment: @Chris The questioner wants to get this result `[0, 3, 4, 7, 8, 11]` this is what the questioner wants

Comment: Apparently this _is_ what OP wanted, based on the ✓. It's not what they _asked for_, though. It happens to work in the case where the lists are already sorted and the values in each list are already interleaved.

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [7,8,9]

c = [None] * (len(a) + len(b))
c[0::2] = a
c[1::2] = b
print(c)
## [1, 7, 2, 8, 3, 9]
```

BTW, this is called "interleaving", search the forum for other options.

Comment: OP, see [How slicing in Python works](https://stackoverflow.com/q/509211/354577) for background on the `c[0::2]`, `c[1::2]` notation

Answer (score 1):

If both lists have the same number of items, just use `zip` and list compression:

```
count = 12

list1 = list(range(0, count, 4))
list2 = list(range(3, count, 4))

newlist = [item for pair in zip(list1, list2) for item in pair]
#[0, 3, 4, 7, 8, 11]
```

Which, using "traditional" for cycles and `list.append`, would be equivalent to:

```
newlist = []
for pair in zip(list1, list2):
    for item in pair:
        newlist.append(item)
```

Answer (score -1):

[`zip`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) the lists together, then flatten them with [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```py
import itertools

l1 = [1, 2, 3]
l2 = [4, 5, 6]

list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip(l1, l2)))
# => [1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6]
```

This works because `zip` gives a list of pairs:

```py
list(zip(l1, l2))
# => [(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```

And `itertools.chain.from_iterable` [flattens](https://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) them.

This also works with more than two lists:

```py
l1 = [1, 2, 3]
l2 = [4, 5, 6]
l3 = [7, 8, 9]

list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip(l1, l2, l3)))
# => [1, 4, 7, 2, 5, 8, 3, 6, 9]
```